# Can I access another installed app's logo from my bare Expo React Native application?

Tags: react-native, expo

The application I am working on uses React Native Maps and it allows a user to select a preferred navigation app from those installed on the device. I can download images of the various logos from the internet to use with the various buttons on my picker modal, but I would prefer to use the logos the user presses to launch those applications (the images stored on the device -- that one might see in the App Store / Google Play representing those apps). Is it possible to access and use these from my RN application?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right you want to access installed app icons from the bundle id?

**Android**

if that's the case you can get all the installed apps using this library [react-native-installed-application](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-installed-application) and you get the icon from it like this example:

```
import RNInstalledApplication from 'react-native-installed-application';


   RNInstalledApplication.getApps()
    .then(apps => {
      setData(apps)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

and you will get the `icon` as `base64` format

**IOS** [currently not working]:

There's no libraries to archive that currently you can try to modify react-native-installed-apps package to make it work.

```
import AppList from 'react-native-installed-apps';
 
AppList.getAll((apps) => {
  console.log(apps); // array of objects [{ app: 'AppName.app', appPath: '/path/of/the/app', info: plistInfoObject }]
});
```

Comment: It appears this package doesn't have any support for iOS, so I wouldn't be able to maintain a common experience across platforms. This does look like a decent option for Android though.

Comment: I've edit my answer please check it :D

Comment: Thanks. I should be able to fork one/both of these and combine the code into something that will work.

Comment: You're welcome please make it as a correct answer :D

Comment: It appears the package you recommended for iOS doesn't provide support for physical devices. I am hoping somebody has a solution that is all-encompassing.

Comment: It looks like the package doesn't work anymore on IOS, unfortunately there's no libraries to archive that in IOS, You can try to modify the package ..

Comment: I updated my answer hope you accept it and make it the right answer